# Debugging "flow check" Fatal error: out of memory

Tags: flowtype

I am working within a very large javascript project, recently flow has begun to take up excessive amounts of RAM (around 4Gb) to run it's static analysis.

I believe my team introduced packages/files to the project that may be difficult for flow to parse (e.g. a JSON data file).

Is there any way for me to see which files flow is struggling with or see a log of the files it is loading? Alternatively, is there a way to tell flow to "give up" on large files?

Edit: The source of my problem was a 150MB JSON file- I found the file using the command in Lewis C's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

flow has an `ls` command

`flow ls` will print out the list of files that it would parse if it were to start a server.

it's likely that with big javascript projects you might want to ignore node_modules.

Comment: thanks lewis, I can now get the size of all the files flow is parsing with  
`flow ls | xargs du -hs | sort -h`

Answer (score 0):

I now run this command to find all large files (>1MB) that may be hanging flow on any project.

```
#!/bin/bash
flow ls | xargs du -hs --threshold=1M 2>/dev/null | sort -h | cut -f 2 | sed 's|'"$(pwd)"'/||g'
```

Explanation:

`flow ls`: Get all files flow is parsing
`xargs du -hs --threshold=1M 2>/dev/null`: Get all files and their size (if over 1MB).
`sort -h`: Sort resulting files
`cut -f 2`: Remove the size label
`sed 's|'"$(pwd)"'/||g`: Replace the full path to the file with a relative path

*Note: `--threshold` may not be supported on OSX*